# Growth functions of Algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, math, complexity-theory, big-o

Well i have two questions here:-

1. If f(n) is function whose growth rate is to be found then, Is for all three notations will the g(n) be same, like for f(n)=O(g(n)) and similaraly for omega and theta ?
2. Theta notation is "omega and Oh" if in some case if oh and omega functions are different then, how will we find theta function there ?
   Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

O, Θ and Ω notation represent related but very different concepts.  O-notation expresses an *asymptotic upper bound* on the growth rate of a function; it says that the function is eventually bounded from above by some constant multiple of some other function.  Ω notation is similar, but gives a lower bound.  Θ notation gives an asymptotic tight bound - for sufficiently large inputs, the algorithm grows at a rate that is bounded from both above and below by a constant multiple of a function.

If f(n) = O(g(n)), it is **not** necessarily true that f(n) = Ω(g(n)) or that f(n) = Θ(g(n)).  For example, 1 = O(n), but 1 ≠ Ω(n) because n grows strictly faster than 1.

If you find that f(n) = O(g(n)) and Ω(h(n)), where g(n) ≠ h(n), you may have to do a more precise analysis to determine a function j(n) such that f(n) = Θ(j(n)).  If g(n) = Θ(h(n)), then you can conclude that f(n) = Θ(g(n)), but if the upper and lower bounds are different there is no mechanical way to determine the Θ growth rate of the function.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

f(n)=O(g(n)) means that n>N => |f(n)|≤C|g(n)| for some constants N and C.

f(n)=Ω(g(n)) means that n>N => |f(n)|≥C|g(n)| for some constants N and C.

f(n)=Θ(g(n)) means that f(n)=O(g(n)) and f(n)=Ω(g(n)).

It is not possible for all f to find a g such that f(n)=Θ(g(n)) if we want g to be a "good" function (i.e. something like n^r*Log(n)^s). For instance, if f(n)=cos(n)²*n+sin(n)²*n², we have f(n)=O(n²) and f(n)=Ω(n) but we can't find a "good" g such that f(n)=Θ(g(n)).